How to go to next compilation error using IdeaVim?
I would like to create a shortcut to go to next compilation error on Rider using IdeaVim. When I execute GoToNextError the cursor goes to the unused using (line 3) intstead of the compilation error (line 9). I have already searched actionlist but have found nothing that seems to solve this problem.


The GoToNextError action has two modes, one which cycles through all warnings and errors (the "next" in GoToNextError) and the other that cycles to the next highest priority message (the "error" in GoToNextError).
There isn't a separate action for the different behaviour, but you can configure this by hovering over the inspection widget in the top right of the editor, clicking the vertical three dot "more" button, and then clicking the "'Next Error' Action Goes Through" option, to select either "Problems with Highest Priority" or "All Problems".

